# .htaccess proxy slug to another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have an angular site `http://domain1.com/post/some-slug` and i wanted to redirect all spiders to `http://api.domain1.com/static/some-slug`

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ http://api.domain1.com/static/$1 [L]
</ifModule>
```

would it be possible to proxy it without doing a redirect?